# VSCode: workspace specific settings excluded from source control

Tags: visual-studio-code

We share team-specific settings for VS Code just by including .vscode into git. What we want is something like in resharper: workspace specific private config that is excluded from source control and can override some common settings.

How can we achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the user settings using this VSCode extension: [Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync)

If you then remove the workspace settings from the git repository (`.vscode/setting.json`) you can locally overwrite the settings per workspace.

Comment: Every person on our team has different user settings, because we are different. We want to have: 1. User settings. 2. Shared workspace settings (lint settings, trimming of endlines, code style, etc,). 3. Private workspace settings (interpreter paths, etc)

Comment: The current version of VSCode does not provide support for that. You can create a feature request issue on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but something close and works well for my team:

Each user has their user settings usually stored at %HOME%/AppData/Roaming/Code/User on windows, or ~/.config/Code/User on linux. Put font, tab size, and other user specific settings here like computer specific paths.

Use .vscode/settings.json as workspace settings. Check that into version control. Put other more project specific settings here, like trimming whitespace, etc.

As for linting and code style it would depend on which language/extension you are using for that and if that extension supports configuration.

If you are writing in C# you can use an omnisharp.json config file at the root of the project. This config can have style settings that should be enforced on the project. Here is an example config:

```
{
  "formattingOptions": {
    "UseTabs": true,
    "SpaceAfterControlFlowStatementKeyword": false
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that computer path is project specific. E.g. one project needs python 2, other python 3. Thanks for advice.